# CSS and .less: Set a font color if user pick a specific color through web interface

Tags: css, if-statement, colors, less, conditional-statements

I have a web Interface where user can choose a color for a h1 element.
I store this choice in a variable calling @color1

For a specific color ( #333 ) contrast with background are no good so a would to force a specific color to #fff if user pick #333.

How can I perform it in less ?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
h1 (@color1:#fff) when (@color1=#333) {
    color:@color1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LESS doesn’t handle if / else statements. Instead, it provides guarded mixins (mixin when a parameter exists or equals / is inferior / is superior to something).

In **Less** you can use a **guard mixin** like:

```
@body:#333;
h1 {
  color: yellow;
}
h1 when (@body = #000) {
  color: blue;
}
h1 when (@body = #333) {
  color: red;
}
```

**DEMO**

http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/mJihw

Comment: nice...but i notice that if color is not #333 the css result havent set value for color.
Look this:
.mixin (@a) when (@a = #333333) {
  color: #eee !important;
}
h1 a {
 color:@color1;
   .mixin(@color1);

    }
there are another way whitout set important for default color in selector ?

Comment: Yes like an if - else statement. You could always use SASS which supports what you are after.